# Themes are visible in Network, but invisible in sites

Tags: multisite, themes

I'm trying to use different themes on different sites in Multisite Wordpress. I can view, add and delete themes from under the Network:

[image: Network themes]

But under most of the sites, I can see only one default theme:

[image: Site themes]

And only one site can show me multiple themes:

[image: One of the sites' themes]

Why so and how to fix that?

Comment: You need to click "Network Enable" to allow sites to be able to pick them.

Comment: Or enable one or more themes for single site from Network > Sites > (site) > Themes

Comment: Enabling themes for the network works. But why they are visible in one site and not visible in others without network activation? Also, as you can see, all themes are not visible in other sites, so I can not enable them for particular sites only. Is it by design?

Comment: I believe the "main" site on the network can always see all themes.